# ¿Como cargar un wpf dentro de otro?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, wpf

Tratare de poner el contexto claro.
Tengo mucho contenido grafico dentro de mi WPF principal, entonces me gustaría trabajarlo por separado. Para ello tengo mi **main.wpf** y aparte (como ejemplo) **contenido1.wpf** y para instanciarlo estaba utilizando 
`<local:contenido1.wpf/>`
pero me tira el siguiente error.

Este si creo como página

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Page sólo puede tener una Window o un Frame como elemento primario.'
```

Este si creo como ventana

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
HResult=0x80131501
Mensaje = Se produjo una excepción al establecer la propiedad 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content'.
Origen = PresentationFramework
Seguimiento de la pila:
en System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)

Excepción interna 1:
InvalidOperationException: Window debe ser la raíz del árbol. No se puede agregar Window como elemento secundario de Visual.
```

Revise un par de ejemplos pero aun no entiendo como realizar correctamente la inserción. Si alguno puede ayudarme agradesco.

Comment: No se si entiendo muy bien lo que quieres, pero creo intuir que lo que quieres es crear un control de usuario para insertarlo en tu página principal? Echa un vistazo a [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ee462243.aspx)

Comment: eso era exactamente lo que buscaba, no sabia como llamarlo :/ gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Gracias al comentario y ayuda de Pikoh comprendí lo que debía hacer y como.

Se agrega un nuevo Control de Usuario y en el contenedor principal o recurrente que se esté trabajando se puede instanciar, eso usando `<local:/>` (en mi caso) o definiendo el directorio dentro de `xmlns:UserControl` y de esta forma llamar `<UserControl:/>`